# mysql not reading the whole file, skipping rows instead while using `load data local`

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

In one of my assignment problem, I need to read an input file that has **131262** lines.

Following is my code for reading the input:

```
create table batsman_scored(
    id int(10) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    match_id int(10),
    over_id int(10),
    ball_id int(10),
    runs_scored int(10),
    innings_no int(10)
);
load data local infile "data/batsman_scored.csv" 
into table batsman_scored
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 2 rows
;
```

The problem is, for some reason, MySQL is not reading the whole file, instead, it is getting terminated after few lines. I checked the input files, and there is nothing suspicious there.
Mysql output:

```
Query OK, 568 rows affected, 65535 warnings (0.50 sec)
Records: 131260  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 130692  Warnings: 261952
```

Can someone tell, why it's skipping so many rows? When does MySQL skip rows?

I checked that MySQL can store a lot more than `568`.

[CSV data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ypMzbeHPtc2TNwkqnUgSwyQhZR8K3ux7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: If an error occures during LOAD DATA then the rows already loaded are not truncated from the table. Cleck 569th row for incorrectness.

Comment: Your CSV contains 10 values per row whereas the table structure contains 6 columns only. !st copumn in the table is primary key whereas 1st column in CSV contains duplicates. Finally your table structure does not match CSV data.

Comment: Sorry, I just updated the csv link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still waiting for an answer here, but commenting the `auto_increment` line:

```
create table batsman_scored(
    // id int(10) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    match_id int(10),
    over_id int(10),
    ball_id int(10),
    runs_scored int(10),
    innings_no int(10)
);
load data local infile "data/batsman_scored.csv" 
into table batsman_scored
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 2 rows
;
```

Comment: Why can't I use the auto_increment thing here? I was thinking to use it as a primary key?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```sql
create table batsman_scored(
    id int(10) unsigned auto_increment primary key,
    match_id int(10),
    over_id int(10),
    ball_id int(10),
    runs_scored int(10),
    innings_no int(10)
);

load data local infile "data/batsman_scored.csv" 
into table batsman_scored
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 2 rows
(match_id, over_id, ball_id, runs_scored, innings_no)
;
```

The values for `id` column are not stored in CSV (the table contains 6 columns whereas CSV contains 5 values per row), and they wouldn'd be loaded from the file, they are generated by autoincrement during importing. So the columns list for loading must be specified, w/o `id` column.

Comment: @AnupamKumar Pay attention - in CSV the composite primary key is specified. So either remove `id` from the structure and create composite PK as specified in CSV or create composite unique key according to the data in CSV header.

Comment: Sry for the typo in the instructions in the CSV files, those cannot be used as the primary key.

I had to add some primary key in this table, so I added that auto_increment line.